# How to get the global keydown event in Reflex?

Tags: ghcjs, reflex

My current attempt at getting an event of *global* keypress (eg: user hits a keyboard shortcut, from anywhere in the UI, to trigger opening of modal dialog) is:

```hs
  prerender_ blank $ do
    -- ctx <- askJSM
    doc <- currentDocumentUnchecked
    win <- currentWindowUnchecked
    let clicked = traceEvent "hit" $ keydown Enter win
    widgetHold_ (text "Waiting") $
      ffor clicked $ \() -> do
        text "CLICKED"
```

However, this fails to typecheck

```
    • Could not deduce: DomEventType JSDOM.Types.Window 
'KeydownTag ~ Word arising from a use of ‘keydown’
```

[Looking at the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-dom-core-0.5/docs/src/Reflex.Dom.Builder.Class.html#HasDomEvent), only `Element EventResult d t` has an instance, but not `Window` or `Document`.

What is the idiomatic way to achieve what I'm trying to do here, in reflex / ghcjs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this can be done in reflex current version:

```hs
import qualified JSDOM as DOM
import qualified JSDOM.EventM as EventM
import qualified JSDOM.Generated.GlobalEventHandlers as Events
import Reflex.Dom.Core

globalKeyEventDemo :: (DomBuilder t m, Prerender t m) => m ()
globalKeyEventDemo =
  prerender_ blank $ do
    document <- DOM.currentDocumentUnchecked
    evEnter <- wrapDomEventMaybe document (`EventM.on` Events.keyDown) $ do
      key <- getKeyEvent
      pure $
        if keyCodeLookup (fromIntegral key) == Enter
          then Just ()
          else Nothing
    let evEnterTraced = traceEvent "hit" evEnter
    widgetHold_ (text "Waiting") . ffor evEnterTraced $ \() -> do
      text "ENTER"
```

Basically [`wrapDomEventMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-dom-core-0.8.1.0/docs/Reflex-Dom-Builder-Immediate.html#v:wrapDomEventMaybe) lets you bind a low-level DOM event to a reflex event. I use a similar approach to get a [global click event](https://github.com/jecaro/diverk/blob/10dfd12191e93f25901528a717cf6e65fe9eb0e7/frontend/src/Reflex/Extra.hs) in my app [Diverk](https://github.com/jecaro/diverk/).

This is not something I came up with from nowhere tho. I have found an example of its use in [rhyolite repo](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/rhyolite/blob/7589b06da525303584d6b8b5d7999df9b674f773/widgets/src/Reflex/Dom/Modal/Base.hs#L187).